# Rexster passing values to functions defined in scripts

Tags: titan, rexster

I have a script named /tmp/scripts/a.gremlin which contains a single function filterOver.

```
def filterOver(age) {
  return g.V.filter{it.age > age}
}
```

My rexster configuration conf/rexster-cassandra.xml contains the correct extensions section.

```
<extensions>
  <allows>
    <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
  </allows>
  <extension>
    <namespace>tp</namespace>
      <name>gremlin</name>
      <configuration>
        <scripts>/tmp/scripts</scripts>
        <allow-client-script>true</allow-client-script>
        <cache-scripts>true</cache-scripts>
      </configuration>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

I have started my rexster server by running

```
bin/titan.sh start
```

Now when I execute

```
http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/tp/gremlin?script=filterOver(30)&load=[a]
```

I get the exception

> {"success":false,"api":{"description":"evaluate an ad-hoc Gremlin
>   script for a graph.","parameters":{"rexster.showTypes":"displays the
>   properties of the elements with their native data type (default is
>   false)","load":"a list of 'stored procedures' to execute prior to the
>   'script' (if 'script' is not specified then the last script in this
>   argument will return the values","returnTotal":"when set to true, the
>   full result set will be iterated and the results returned (default is
>   false)","language":"the gremlin language flavor to use (default is
>   groovy)","params":"a map of parameters to bind to the script
>   engine","script":"the Gremlin script to be
>   evaluated","rexster.returnKeys":"an array of element property keys to
>   return (default is to return all element
>   properties)","rexster.offset.start":"start index for a paged set of
>   data to be returned","rexster.offset.end":"end index for a paged set
>   of data to be
>   returned"}},"message":"","error":"javax.script.ScriptException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.filterOver()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [30]"}

I have also tried

```
http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/tp/gremlin?params={%22age%22:30}&script=filterOver(age)&load=[a]
```

and even the following

```
http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/tp/gremlin?age=30&script=filterOver(age)&load=[a]
```

So what is the correct way of passing parameters to functions?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your specific configuration and it works for me.  Your `rexster.xml` configuration seems to look right, as does your `a.gremlin`.  There doesn't seem to be a problem with keeping that script in `/tmp/scripts`.  This specific call with cURL worked for me:

```
curl "http://localhost:8182/graphs/tinkergraph/tp/gremlin?script=filterOver(30)&load=\[a\]"
```

If trying with cURL doesn't work for you I would suggest simplifying your rig, and trying with just a download of Rexster itself.  Make sure that works and if it does then simulate again with Titan Server.